# If statement shifting cells

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I currently have this If MsgBox Statement. If vbYes is selected, it will edit cell H8, if vbNo is selected, it will edit a cell 3 below that (H11).

```
If MsgBox("Is X? ", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
'do this to cell H8
'do this to cell h9
else
'do this to cell h11
'do this to cell h12
end if
```

The edits are the same - the only difference is the cell is offset 3 cells down. In this example I only use H8 and H9 but in my data there are many more cells being updated. This makes my code messy. Is there an easy way to consolidate this?

Comment: If the offset of cells are consistent, you can use a loop to set the values

Comment: Are the lines following? Like 3.4.5.6.7 and 10.11.12.13.14 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim i as Long, j as string
i = 8
j = "Whatever edit is"
If MsgBox("Is X? ", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
    Cells(i, "H").Value = j 'if Yes
Else
    Cells(i+3, "H").Value = j 'if No
End If
```

If you want to loop i for different values, this would be pretty quick.

```
For i = 8 to 200 Step 1
    'do soemthing using i
Next i
```

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this - Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
'Make a range first
Set WorkingRange = '(YourRangeHere)'
If MsgBox("Is X? ", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbNo Then
    Set WorkingRange = WorkingRange.Offset(3)
End If

'Do this with WorkingRange here
```